# Jsoup method not storing data into TextView after creating Document from HTML page

Tags: android, jsoup

I tried this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        netAccess();
        text = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    }

    public void netAccess()
    {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/").get();
            String word = doc.title();
            text.setText(word);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But after I initialize "doc" nothing happens, the TextView doesn't change, and "word" does not change its value. I used Android Studio's debugging to see if the value changed and the TextView just didn't update for some reason, but nothing happens. I've tried it on multiple AVD's. Nothing I can find indicates why it won't work, I substituted title() for text() and nothing changed.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/").get();
String word = doc.title();
text.setText(word);
```

I'm sure there is something obvious I am overlooking. Can anybody see it?

Comment: You are doing this heavy operation on the main thread. So it is throwing Network on Main thread exception. Put Debugger in Catch block. It will come here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this operation in another thread. You can try AsynkTask this. Since it is deprecated now, I am just giving you an example.

```
public void netAccess()
{
    new MyTask().execute();
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String title  = "";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com/").get();
            title = doc.title();
            Log.v("MYJSOUP", title);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I understand now, you can't update the UI inside the thread unless you use onPostExecute, but you set it on the right track, thanks a bunch.